# SQL Server: avg sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, average

I'm trying to find the average of the sum of a column. With the code below:

```
select  avg(sum(totalSpend)) as HHtypetotalSpend,
        HHtype 
from dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
GROUP BY HHtype, totalSpend;
```

I get there error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Is there a way to get the average of the sum of the columns with the built in `avg()` function, or do I need to count the rows and divide the sum by the number of rows?

**AFTER EDIT:**

Here's my code thanks to some answers to my question:

```
  SELECT SUM(totalSpend)/SUM(numVisits) AS totalSpend, HHtype
  FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
  GROUP BY HHtype
```

But I get this error message:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

Any idea on how to fix this? Should I create a function to remove the rows with 0 in the `numVisits`?

**AFTER ANOTHER EDIT:**

Here is my code now. It is a function:

```
DROP FUNCTION getHHtypeTotalSpendAvg

GO
CREATE FUNCTION getHHtypeTotalSpendAvg()
RETURNS float
BEGIN
DECLARE @HHtypetotalSpendAvg float
DECLARE @ANTHEM_IDS_JR_TABLE table (numVisits int, totalSpend float)

INSERT into @ANTHEM_IDS_JR_TABLE select numVisits as numVisits, totalSpend as totalSpend from dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR--(dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR.numVisits, dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR.totalSpend)
-- SET @ANTHEM_IDS_JR_TABLE=dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR.numVisits, dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR.totalSpend
-- select @HHtypetotalSpendAvg = sum(totalSpend)/sum(numVisits), HHtype from dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR GROUP BY HHtype;
DELETE numVisits from @ANTHEM_IDS_JR_TABLE WHERE numVisits=0
DELETE totalSpend from @ANTHEM_IDS_JR_TABLE WHERE totalSpend=NULL
select @HHtypetotalSpendAvg = sum(totalSpend)/sum(numVisits) from dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR GROUP BY HHtype;

RETURN @HHtypetotalSpendAvg
END;

GO
EXEC getHHtypeTotalSpendAvg`
```

But i get the error message:

> Invalid object name 'numVisits'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The average of a Sum would be the sum...Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question...

Comment: @Steve P : he wants to sum in group and then divide the sum by the number of rows in group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use one aggregate function in another :

```
  SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(numVisits) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(totalSpend)/SUM(numVisits) END) AS totalSpend
       , HHtype
  FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
  GROUP BY HHtype, totalSpend
```

Comment: That answer my question, but now, due to 0's being in my data set, I have an error: `Divide by zero encountered`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I looked up case and did this with my code: `  SELECT HHtype, SUM(totalSpend)/SUM(numVisits) AS totalSpend =
  CASE jerryCase
    WHEN 0 THEN 1
  END  
  FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
  GROUP BY HHtype` but I have multiple errors

Comment: @pbars23 : actually, I can't understand why `COUNT` returns 0. Anyway,your `CASE` syntax is not valid, look at my example.

Comment: I changed `count` to `sum` because of the objective of my code.

Comment: @pbars23 : Then you,please, elaborate.Why?

Comment: I'm trying to sum up the number of visits someone has to a restaurant and then use that to divide the sum of how much they spent there so I can see how much they spend on average each time they're there.

Answer (score 0):

AVG of a Sum does not make much sense In my opinion, because if you already have created the sum you only have 1 value from which you are creating the AVG. You will always get the same AVG as the SUM